# UdpClient receive buffer. When does it drop packets?

Tags: buffer, udpclient

I have a UdpClient sat on a port. I use it to send data.

99% of the time I don't care about any incoming packets. However, on rare occasions I need to listen for a response from one of my sent packets.

My first thought is to simple call UdpClient.Recieve() straight after the send, and loop through any packets until I find my reply.

However, I am wondering how the recieve buffer works in UdpClient. Since I am not processing any received packets normally, I assume it must buffer them and then throw them away when the buffer reaches a certain size. I am concerned that this throwing away might happen just after my reply arrives on the wire, but before my Recieve() call has executed.

The only solution I can think of it to continually process all received packets asynchronously, but this seems overkill for such a simple situation.

Does anyone know the buffering behaviour of UdpClient? (eg does it throw away the entire buffer, or just the oldest data or what?). MSDN gives no detail that I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Networking drivers will use ring buffers of varying size.

```
Ring Buffer: [Slot 1] [ Slot 2] [Slot 3]
Incoming Data: AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD EEEE FFFF

Ring Buffer: [DDDD] [EEEE] [FFFF]
```

The exact size is usually driver dependent, but that's irrelevant to your question.

You should be fine only doing a RECV processing loop when you are actually waiting for a response.